# Filtering a relationship attribute in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have some code with a `Widget` object that must undergo some processing periodically.  Widgets have a relationship to a `Process` object that tracks individual processing attempts and holds data about those attempts, such as state information, start and end times, and the result.  The relationship looks something like this:

```
class Widget(Base):
   _tablename_ = 'widget'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = Column(String)
   attempts = relationship('Process')

class Process(Base):
   _tablename_ = 'process'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   widget_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey='widget.id'))
   start = Column(DateTime)
   end = Column(DateTime)
   success = Column(Boolean)
```

I want to have a method on `Widget` to check whether it's time to process that widget yet, or not.  It needs to look at all the attempts, find the most recent successful one, and see if it is older than the threshold.

One option is to iterate `Widget.attempts` using a list comprehension.  Assuming `now` and `delay` are reasonable `datetime` and `timedelta` objects, then something like this works when defined as a method on `Widget`:

```
def ready(self):
   recent_success = [attempt for attempt in self.attempts if attempt.success is True and attempt.end >= now - delay]
   if recent_success:
      return False
   return True
```

That seems like good idiomatic Python, but it's not making good use of the power of the SQL database backing the data, and it's probably less efficient than running a similar SQL query especially once there are a large number of Process objects in the `attempts` list.  I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to implement this as a query, though.

It's easy enough to run the query inside `Widget` something like this:

```
def ready(self):
   recent_success = session.query(Process).filter(
      and_(
         Process.widget_id == self.id,
         Process.success == True,
         Process.end >= now - delay
      )
   ).order_by(Process.end.desc()).first()
   if recent_success:
      return False
   return True
```

But I run into problems in unit tests with getting `session` set properly inside the module that defines Widget.  It seems to me that's a poor style choice, and probably not how SQLAlchemy objects are meant to be structured.

I could make the `ready()` function something external to the Widget class, which would fix the problems with setting `session` in unit tests, but that seems like poor OO structure.

I think the ideal would be if I could somehow filter `Widget.attempts` with SQL-like code that's more efficient than a list comprehension, but I haven't found anything that suggests that's possible.

What is actually the best approach for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking in the right direction. Any solution *within* the `Widget` instance implies you need to process all instances. Seeking the *external* process would have better performance and easier testability.

You can get all the `Widget` instances which need to be scheduled for next processing using this query:

```
q = (
    session
    .query(Widget)
    .filter(Widget.attempts.any(and_(
        Process.success == True,
        Process.end >= now - delay,
    )))
)

widgets_to_process = q.all()
```

If you really want to have a property on the model, i would not create a separate query, but just use the relationship:

```
def ready(self, at_time):
    successes = [
        attempt 
        for attempt in sorted(self.attempts, key=lambda v: v.end)
        if attempt.success and attempt.end >= at_time  # at_time = now - delay
    ]
    return bool(successes)
```

Comment: These examples actually return all the widgets that are NOT ready to process, since they list Widgets that have had a successful processing run within the delay threshold.  I need Widgets that have no successful processing runs within the delay threshold.  However, it confirms I'm more or less on the right track.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. Please edit the answer with the correct logic for completeness, if you feel like it. Change `and_` to `or_` and add `not(...)` to get the opposite result.